# How to display different kind of items in listbox2 when selecting one of the option in listbox1 without any button clicking in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, listbox

How can I display the items in listbox2 when selecting one of the option in listbox1 without any button clicking by using Select Case Statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an [event handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/handles-clause) to your ListBox1 [SelectedIndexChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case ListBox1.SelectedIndex
        'Change your ListBox2
    End Select
End Sub
```

Let's do an example:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Show A")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Show B")
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ListBox2.Items.Clear() 'Remove existing items
    Select Case ListBox1.SelectedIndex
        Case 0 'Show A is selected
            ListBox2.Items.Add("Example A (1)")
            ListBox2.Items.Add("Example A (2)")
            ListBox2.Items.Add("Example A (3)")
        Case Else 'Show B is selected
            ListBox2.Items.Add("Example B (1)")
            ListBox2.Items.Add("Example B (2)")
    End Select
End Sub
```

The output will be:

[image: Output]